# Inicialización infinita de Debian

Tags: linux, debian

Tengo un portátil con Debian 9 (stretch) y todo partió porque inicialmente tenía un problema, no tenia wifi, entonces me decidí a instalar unas cosas (que no funcionaron):

```
apt install firmware-realtek
apt-get install firmware-linux-nonfree
apt install firmware-netxen
apt-get update
```

Luego instale steam, y no me abrian los juego entonces intenté arreglarlo:

```
apt install libgtk2.0-0:i386
```

Posteriormente lo reinicié y me encuentro que cuando prendé se quedá así y nunca termina de inicializarse:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]
Foto sacada de [aquí](https://askubuntu.com/questions/779251/what-to-do-after-failed-to-start-load-kernel-modules)

Cuando pongo `apt-get update` en el recovery mode me devuelve esto y no me lo resuelve:

```
W: Fallo al obtener http://deb.debian.org/debian/dists/stretch/InRelease No se pudo resolver <<deb.debian.org>>
W: Fallo al obtener http://security.debian.org/dists/stretch/updates/InRelease No se pudo resolver <<security.debian.org>>
W: Fallo al obtener http://ftp.us.debian.org/debian/dists/stretch-proposed-updates/InRelease No se pudo resolver <<ftp.us.debian.org>>
```

Quisiera que volviera a abrirse debian de manera normal.

Actualización 1: Ahora cuando prendo el computador con Debian de manera normal se pone esta pantalla y nunca termina de inicializarse:

[image: Al iniciar debian]

Busqué [aquí](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/348806/acpi-exception-ae-not-found-infinitely-on-startup), pero no entiendo mucho.

Actualización 2: Encontré [esto](https://www.quijotelibre.com/2017/10/12/acpi-error-una-tonteria-de-gnulinux-que-me-ha-vuelto-loco/) y ahora el pc muestra se queda pegado en esto:
[image: debian]

Comment: Lo que comentas son varios problemas. Empiezas por problemas con la tarjeta WiFi, sigues con Steam y terminas con problemas con los repositorios (son cosas que no tienen que ver entre sí). ¿Por qué no pruebas a subdividir los problemas para poder centrarse en cada uno?. Para el problema de la tarjeta WiFi estaría bien que ejecutaras desde una terminal `sudo lspci | grep Network` y pegaras la salida.

Comment: Es que el problema que quiero solucionar es el de que inicié Debian, pero creo que contando que pasó antes de que pasará eso pueden tener una idea de como solucionarlo. P.D.: el output de lo que me pides es:
04:00.0 Network controller: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd RTL8822BE 802.11a/b/g/n/ac WiFi adapter

Comment: Resolver varios problemas después de "trastear" con el sistema puede ser muy complicado, especialmente si no se sabe todo lo que se ha hecho. Yo intentaría empezar desde 0 abordando uno por uno cada problema (es una opinión personal) Parece que el driver de esa tarjeta se incluyó en el kernel 4.14 https://www.phoronix.com/scan.php?page=news_item&px=Linux-Realtek-RTL8822BE Lo he comprobado y sí: https://github.com/torvalds/linux/tree/master/drivers/staging/rtlwifi/rtl8822be . Qué versión del kernel tienes? (comando: `uname -a`)

Comment: @Arg0s el output de `uname -a` es `Linux elborito 4.9.0-8-amd64 #1 SMP Debian 4.9.130-2 (2018-10-27) x86_64 GNU/Linux`

Comment: Tienes el kernel 4.9, así que deberías actualizar a la versión 4.14 o superior para solucionar los problemas con la tarjeta WiFi. Si tu intención es usar Linux para Steam, tal vez haya otras distribuciones más "amigables" (Ubuntu, Manjaro, Mint, Antergos, etc)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

La solución la encontré [aquí](https://askubuntu.com/questions/826622/booting-problem-ubuntu-gnome-16-04-01-lts). Solo tuvé que poner las siguientes líneas de código en "Recovery Mode":

```
 mount -o rw,remount /
 apt-get purge nvidia-*
 reboot
```

Pero no sé realmente por qué funciona.

Comment: Lo que hacen esas líneas de código es montar tu partición raíz con permisos de lectura y escritura (primera linea) para luego eliminar los drivers y archivos de configuración relativos a nvidia (segunda línea) y luego reiniciar para ver los cambios,

Comment: Fantástico, te lo agradezco. Si te gustaria poner más en detalle la respuesta, puedes ponerla [aquí](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/226434/por-qu%c3%a9-nvidia-me-caus%c3%b3-problemas) donde pregunté un poco más en detalle