# ¿Por qué Nvidia me causó problemas?

Tags: linux, unix

Tengo un portátil con Debian 9 (stretch) y todo partió porque instalé steam (según [la wiki de debian](https://wiki.debian.org/es/Steam#Instalaci.2BAPM-n)) de la siguiente manera:

```
dpkg --add-architecture i386
apt update
apt install steam
```

Después instalé algo relacionado con Nvidia (siguiendo lo que decía en la wiki):

```
apt install libgl1-nvidia-glx:i386
```

Luego no se abrían los juegos, entonces según la misma [página](https://wiki.debian.org/es/Steam#Steam_funciona.2C_pero_no_se_pueden_iniciar_juegos) se solucionaba así:

```
apt install libgtk2.0-0:i386
```

Posteriormente lo reinicié y me encuentro que cuando prendé nunca inicia Debian y muestra estos códigos muchas veces repetido en la pantalla:

```
[  OK  ] Started Session c1 of user gdm.
[  OK  ] Started User Manager for UID 117...
         Stopping User Manager for UID 117...
```

Después de postear el problema de manera incompleta y un día completo buscando solución, encuentro una respuesta [aquí](https://askubuntu.com/questions/826622/booting-problem-ubuntu-gnome-16-04-01-lts) donde, en consecuencia, yo pusé las siguientes líneas de código en "Recovery Mode":

```
 mount -o rw,remount /
 apt-get purge nvidia-*
 reboot
```

Comprendo que Nvidia me causó problemas pero mi inglés es un poco limitado, entonces aquí pregunto ¿Por qué pasó esto? y ¿Cómo estas líneas de código lo arreglaron?

Comment: algo a la hora de instalar el Driver **propietario** de Nvidia dio conflicto con el X11/Xorg o algun software que realiza uso o llamados en bajo nivel hacia el controlador de Graficos. Nvidia es bien conocido por proveer soporte... digamos limitado y muy a puertas cerradas sobre sus controladores y Hardware. por tanto en algunos casos pasa que un software X hace llamados de bajo nivel hacia OpenGL, Vulkan, O alguna funcion grafica y falla de forma Desastrosa. ademas el repocitorio de Ubuntu hasta donde lei segun dice no tiene los "drivers mas recientes"

Comment: Voto por cerrar esta pregunta como tema no relacionado porque  no es un problema de programación.

Comment: Es una pregunta de programación, porque estoy preguntando cómo funcionaron las líneas de código